# Windows Phone 8 fire a background task on call picked without accessing any call details

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am looking to develop an application where i just need to detect whenever a call is picked up.

I do not need any details related to call log and just need the event to be fired which will manipulate the sensors and do some functionality.

Is it possible to have that kind of access. Is it available out of the box and if not, is there a way that I can request for access from Microsoft?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WP apps don't have this kind of access/functionality.

Only possible way would be to use the `Obscured Event` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationframe.obscured%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) Which requires your app to be launched all the time you want to capture the activity.

The problem here is that Obscured event is also fired in the case of alarm or lockscreen.

I doubt Microsoft will grant you access to more functionality.

Comment: This won't solve my purpose as I need the app to be running in background. Are apps like TrueCaller gives access to special API's for which general developers do not have access??

Comment: Maybe will have to move to android development in that case.